# Use fluid viewhelper inside own viewhelper which creates html code

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

I created a own viewhelper for my extension, which creates dynamic html code.
I use

```
protected $escapeOutput = false;
```

in my extension. The html code for the Fluid viewhelper will be returned inside a string.

```
<f:image src='".$lPlay->getIfName()."' alt='Bild' height='50' />
```

But the Fluid viewhelper is not executed. In the source code of the web page I can see

```
<f:image src='fileadmin/user_upload/AlbumArtSmall.jpg' alt='Bild' height='50' />
```

What is my mistake or is it not possible to use a viewhelper inside a viewhelper, which creates html code.
Maybe I could call the fluid viewhelper inside my viewhelper directly with php. But I don't know how to do it.

```
    public function render() {
    $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
    $lPlayC = $objectManager->get('HGA\\Mairlist\\Controller\\LastPlayController');
    $lPlays = $lPlayC->sendAction();
    $return  = "\n<div class='lPlay'>\n";
    $return .= "\t<table  class='tx_mairlist' >\n";
    $return .= "\t\t<tr class='header'>\n";
    $return .= "\t\t\t<th colspan='3'><p class='header'>gerade gespielt</p></th>\n";
    $return .= "\t\t</tr>\n";
    $iPos = 1;
    foreach ($lPlays as $lPlay) {
        if ($iPos == 1) {
            $class = "onair";
        } else {
            $class = "gone";
        }
        $return .= "<tr class='".$class."'>\n";
        $date = $lPlay->getDate();
        $temp = $date->format('H:i:s');
        $return .= "<td class='time'> <p class='time'>".$temp."</p>\n";
        $return .= "<p class='space'></br></p>\n";
        $return .= "<p class='duration'>".$lPlay->getDuration()."</p>\n";
        $return .= "</td>\n";
        $return .= "<td> <f:image src='".$lPlay->getIfName()."' alt='Bild' height='50' /></td>\n";
        $return .= "<td> <img src='".PATH_site.$lPlay->getIfName()."' alt='Bild' height='50' /></td>\n";
        $return .= "<td class='info'><b>".$lPlay->getTitle()."</b></br><p class='artist'>".$lPlay->getArtist()."</p></td>\n";
        $return .= "</tr>\n";
        $iPos++;
    }
    $return .= "</table>\n";
    $return .= "</div>\n";
    error_log("ViewHelper: " . $return, 0);
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the render()  function of your ViewHelper class.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the HTML output in your template. You can add a variable to Fluid in your ViewHelper and render its children:

```php
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
$lPlayC = $objectManager->get('HGA\\Mairlist\\Controller\\LastPlayController');
$lPlays = $lPlayC->sendAction();
$this->templateVariableContainer->add('plays', $lPlays);
$output = $this->renderChildren();
$this->templateVariableContainer->remove('plays');
return $output;
```

In your template you can then use this ViewHelper like:

```
<ns:myViewHelper>
    <div class="lPlay">
        <table  class="tx_mairlist">
            <tr class="header">
                <th colspan="3"><p class="header">gerade gespielt</p></th>
            </tr>
            <f:for each="{plays}" as="play" iteration="iteration">
                <tr class="{f:if(condition: iteration.isFirst, then: 'onair', else: 'gone')}">
                    <td class="time">
                        <p class="time"><f:format.date format="H:i:s">{play.date}</f:format.date></p>
                        <p class="space"><br /></p>
                        <p class="duration">{play.duration}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <f:image src="{play.ifName}" alt="Bild" height="50" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="info">
                        <b>{play.title}</b></br>
                        <p class="artist">{play.artist}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </f:for>
        </table>
    </div>
</ns:myViewHelper>
```

Comment: Rudy, could you please explaint it a little bit more. In the template I see 3 times ... . Are this the children? When yes, how can I handle the different children? Or is it only the code inside the for loop and how do I call the children in the template?

Comment: With `$this->templateVariableContainer->add('plays', $lPlays);` you add the data from $lPlays as a variable for Fluid. With `$this->renderChildren();` you render the part of the template inside your ViewHelper tag (the children), where you can use the added variable just like any other variable in Fluid. You of course have to add the HTML yourself. I just added the for loop to show you can use that variable. `$this->templateVariableContainer->remove('plays');` removes the variable from Fluid, so it won't be available outside your ViewHelper tag.

Comment: Rudy, my problem is, that I currently not understood, where I have to make the changes. In dependency from the play variable I want to modify the html-code. If I put the html-code into the template, how can I do the modifications and can I control, where the return $output in my tamplate will be placed. For example, inside the for loop I would like to change the class name fron <td class="....">. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I've added a more complete template in my answer based on your code. I'm assuming `play.ifName` has the full path to the image. If it's just the file name, you'll have to add the path like `<f:image src="path/to/image/{play.ifName}" alt="Bild" height="50" />`